# Allow editing of table widget item only on double click event

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

How to disable editing of cell on single click event and only allow it on double click event?

```
self.table_field.double_click_row(self.edit_cell)
```

I tried to disable the editing of cell using this:

```
item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
self.table_field.set_item(0, 1, item)
```

But how can I edit it again when the user double click the cell?

Comment: You could try something like `table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked)`

Comment: @Heike, do you know why I can still edit cell on single click? ```self.table_field= TableWidget()``` ```self.table_field.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked)```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make QTableView to enter the editing mode only on double-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186118/how-to-make-qtableview-to-enter-the-editing-mode-only-on-double-click)